# Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that the sequence $(a_{n+1}-a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is convergent to a non-zero real number.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that the sequence $(a_{n+1}-a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is convergent to a non-zero real number. Evaluate the limit $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right)^n.$$

Suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=L>0$. Then given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq\mathbb{N}$, $$L-\epsilon\leq a_{n+1}-a_n\leq L+\epsilon$$. From this how to approach?

Comment: Always a good idea to start with examples.  Can you produce any sequence $\{a_n\}$ with the desired property?  What is the limit in the examples you can find?  Once you have a few examples, you should have a good idea as to the answer, and that is always a big help.

Comment: Nice exercise, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: With the same notation as your approach, show that there exists $R\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, you have
$$
\lvert a_n-nL-R\rvert\leq n\varepsilon.
$$
Hence attack the question along the line
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\approx 1+\frac{1}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and pick $N$ accordingly.
We may asssume wlog that $\epsilon<\frac L8$ so that
$$ 1+\frac1L\epsilon<1+\frac2L\epsilon-\frac8{L^2}\epsilon^2=\left(1+\frac4L\epsilon\right)\left(1-\frac2L\epsilon\right)$$
and hence
$$\tag10<\frac{1+\frac1L\epsilon}{1-\frac2L\epsilon}<1+\frac4L\epsilon $$
For $n>N$, we conclude $$(n-N)L-(n-N)\epsilon<a_n-a_N<(n-N)L+(n-N)\epsilon,$$ hence
$$ |a_n-nL|<(|a_N-NL|+N\epsilon)+n\epsilon$$
or
$$ \left|\frac {a_n}L-n\right|<c+\frac nL\epsilon.$$
For $n\gg 0$ this means
$$ \left|\frac {a_n}L-n\right|<\frac {2n}L\epsilon.$$

Thus 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}<1+\frac{1+ \frac1L\epsilon}{(1-\frac 2L\epsilon)n}<1+\frac{1+\frac4L\epsilon}n $$
and
$$ \limsup\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n\le \lim\left(1+\frac{1+\frac4L\epsilon}{n}\right)^n=e^{1+\frac4L\epsilon}.$$
As this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, we have
$$ \limsup\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n\le e.$$
By the same method, we can show that 
$$ \liminf\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n\ge e$$
and conclude
$$ \lim\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^n= e.$$